# Class doesn't support operators

Tags: c++, class, operators

I created a vector out of a struct to store multiple types of values. However, I can't get input to work.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

struct People{
       string name;
       int age;
};

int main()
{
    vector<People>nameage;
    cout << "Enter name then age until done. Press enter, 0, enter to continue.:\n";
    People name;
    People age;
    while(name != "0"){
                 cin >> name;
                 nameage.push_back(name);
                 cin >> age;
                 nameage.push_back(age);}
    vector<People>::iterator i = (nameage.end()-1);
    nameage.erase(i);    
}
```

I've also tried having the name and age variables in the main function be string/int types, and while that fixes the operator issue, it leads to an issue with function calling in the push_back line.

P.S. Is it possible to push_back multiple inputs such as...

```
cin >> name >> age;
nameage.push_back(name,age);
```

?

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not do:

```
People p;
cin >> p.name;
cin >> p.age;
nameage.push_back( p );
```

You can't just `cin >>` p, as `istream` doesn't understand how to input a "People" object. So you can either define `operator>>` for `People`, or you can just read in the individual fields into a People object.

Also, note, you need to `push_back` an object of type `People`, as that is what your `vector` is -- it is a `People` container.

Comment: This way worked, but now I'm trying to output the vector. Do I need to define operator << for People?

Comment: You could, or you could output the members separately.

Comment: One popular way is to define operator<<() in terms of the operator<<() of each member separately, with some sort of way to distinguish the fields.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to define an `operator>>` for People.

```
struct People
{
    friend std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & in, People & person);
};

std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & in, People & person)
{
    in >> person.name >> person.age;
    return in;
}
```

Then you could write:

```
Person p;
cout << "Enter the person's name and age, separated by a space: ";
cin >> p;
nameage.push_back (p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean:

```
People person;
while( cin >> person.name >> person.age && person.age != 0){
  nameage.push_back(person);
}
```

Or better yet you can overload the >> operator but it looks like you're looking for a more beginner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to declare name as a string and age as an int in the main(). You are declaring them as `People` . This will not compile unless you have overloaded the operator >>.